# OCI policy deny access to Identity providers

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

in OCI I want to allow access to a specific user group to manage all resources in compartment, except  for Identity Providers (in this case, of *Social* type). **I'm aware that OCI doesn't let for explicit deny**, but with conditions I managed, for example, to write this policy:

```
Allow group '<domain>'/'<user_group>' to manage all-resources in compartment <compartment> where request.operation != 'ListUsers'
```

which, in fact, denies access to *list user* operation.

I'm searching for a way to replace *ListUsers* with *ListIdentityProviders*, but all Identity Providers-related operations are deprecated, look here: https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/identity/20160918/IdentityProvider/ListIdentityProviders

Resulting in the users belonging to the user group to access and view identity provider details.

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!